# How to order by a summation of integers in descending order with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm creating a website in which I have to use PHP to pull out of a MySQL database and for this project I need to `SELECT Total sales by customerName ORDER BY Total sales DESCending` from my table. This is my table (the "sales" table):
[image]

I need to have it output this to a table (but it is the actual information not just "Customer" or "Total Sales"):

```
<tr>
    <td>Customer</td>
    <td>Total Sales</td>
    <td>Time of Sale</td>
    <td>Sales Department</td>
    <td>Item Sold</td>
    <td>Number of Items Sold</td>
    <td>Cost per Item</td>
    <td>Sales Person</td>
</tr>;
```

So basically I need to know how to have an SQL statement that pulls the information out of the table called "sales" for every `saleItem` with the `customerName` first, then the total (summation) (not just the number of items for that specific `saleItem`, it has to be every item that the customer has bought) `numberOfItems` that the customer has bought, then the `saleDTM` (time of the sale), then the `saleDept` (the sale department), then the `saleItem` (the item sold), then the `numberOfItems` (the number of items sold for the type of `saleItem`), then the `costPerItem` (the cost of the `saleItem`), then finally the `salesPerson` (the person that sold the `saleItem`). All of that has to be ordered by the total (every item bought by the customer, not just the number of items bought for a specific `saleItem`) `numberOfItems` that the customer has bought. How do I do that SQL statement?

Comment: you can order by multiple fields. ``order by `total sales`, field1, field2, etc...``

Comment: But how do I do that full query?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Number of items customer bought is aggregate of all items (count). time of sale and cost per items will be separate for each item. To best of my knowledge, this wont be possible in one query unless you use lots of sub-queries which is worse than firing separate queries.

Comment: You need to post the table(s) so we know what data your working on. We can't help if we can't see the table structure.

Comment: Does it really make sense to show total sales and the time of *the*  sale together?

Comment: I did post the tables. I don't know what you are talking about user3587554.

Comment: Total sales will be the sum of a bunch of values. Which "Time of sale" do you expect to display with that total? The earliest? The latest? The median? Which "Sales department" do you expect to display with that total?

Comment: In addition to what @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall asked, which item and which sales person, you want to get. Also how you will calculate cost per item, since each item have different cost per item.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the total sales per sales person with something along these lines.

```
select salesPerson, sum(numberOfItems * costPerItem) as total_sales
from sales
group by salesPerson
order by total_sales desc;
```

But there's no way to join that back to the sales table to give you, say, "time of sale" or "sales department".  It just doesn't make sense.

Total sales per customer is similar, but it's also a *different* thing. (In your question, you refer to both "total sales per salesperson" and "total sales per customer".) The individual details--time of sale, sale department, etc--are yet another thing. You *seem* to be talking about three different kinds of reports, but maybe you know something the rest of us don't.

Comment: I never refer to both total sales per salesperson. I don't know where you are getting that from. And what would be the three different kinds of reports?

Comment: In the question *I* answered--the one before your edit--you wrote `SELECT Total sales by SALES_PERSON...`. In *that* question, before your edit--you'd referred to 1) total sales per salesperson, 2) total sales per customer, and 3) something to do with the date/time and department of each sale (which logically *must* be unaggregated, unlike total sales). Since you've heavily edited your question, I'll try to take another look at it sometime today.